# Why doesn't namedtuple use super()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, namedtuple

I was browsing through the source code of `namedtuple` (see [`collections/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L300)) to see how to inherit from `tuple`. I noticed in the `__new__` method, it doesn't call `super()`:

```
def __new__(_cls, {arg_list}):
        'Create new instance of {typename}({arg_list})'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, ({arg_list}))
```

Why does it call `_tuple.__new__`? Isn't the correct way to call a base class method from the subclass to use `super()`? Like so:

```
return super().__new__(cls, ({arg_list}))
```

Comment: Could you share a link to the source please?  That `{arg_list}` syntax isn't valid python, so it's possible that whatever this is *can't* call `super`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh it's string interpolation, `namedtuple`s are `exec`uted strings

Comment: @PatrickHaugh -   https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py  Go to line 310.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - Given what's shown in the above link, in this answer on CR, a call to `namedtuple` instead of `super()` is the right way to do it, correct? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/177829/168710

Comment: The distinction is that they're subclassing from `tuple`, but calling the `__new__` of `builtins.tuple as _tuple`.  I don't know why they make that distinction, but that's the reason they don't call `super()`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code review code you posted, `super` is the correct way of doing things there.   Note that the `namedtuple('AuthorBase', 'id first_name last_name')` that `Author` inherits from is created in the `class` statement, there's no other way to reference that object except through `super`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - Thanks for the clarification.